# How to get Username after user registration

Tags: wordpress

I'm redirecting user to a OTP verification page after user completes his registration. I want to get the username in the redirected page so that i can verify the user but unable to get username as user is not logged in.

How can get the username and fetch the user details from his profile in the redirected page. I'm using WordPress.

TIA

Comment: can you post your registration code?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Issue is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue resolved**

Following code will be triggered after successful user registration. I'm storing the user_id which i got using this action in a session and using in the redirected page.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_theme_registration_do_stuff', 10, 1 );

function my_theme_registration_do_stuff( $user_id ) {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user_ids"] = $user_id;


}
```

Also i'm redirecting user to a custom page after registration using following filter

```
    function wpse_19692_registration_redirect() {
        return home_url( '/custom-page' );
    }

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_19692_registration_redirect' );
```